# Remind me to post that answer later

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications

I have asked a question; then, as the tumbleweed blew through my living room, I fixed it myself, and I forgot I had ever asked.
Now I need to reformat, and clean up the question, but I don't have time or inclination.
Could you put up a reminder so I can mark that question as "hmm I must do that someday" and see it each time I return?

I want to make the site better, just not today.

Comment: There is the "favorite" button (this five-pointed star) which I'm sometimes using to mark questions I want to revisit. Often I forget looking there, though. Other than that, it is generally a good idea to look through your own questions once in a while.

Comment: How's the system supposed to determine that you've actually figured out your problem to remind you? It can probably do automatic reminders for newer users when an answer is not accepted (has its pros and cons)... I know the more well established crowd who knows how the system works will not like this... I certainly won't.

Comment: Leave it open in a browser tab.  Set up a calendar event for yourself with daily reminders.  Something like that.  I see no need for StackExchange to become your personal secretary.

Comment: I'd post an answer to your question, but I'm too lazy to do it right now.  Can you remind me to do it later?

Comment: Your questions are supposed to be about real situations you've actually encountered. If you're asking so many questions you can't keep track of which ones you're still interested in, you're probably asking too many questions instead of doing some basic research.

Answer (score 4):

> I have asked a question ... and I forgot I had ever asked

All four of your questions are on your user profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/571567/paul

Just click on your name at the top of every page and scroll down to "questions" to refer to any of them at any time.

Comment: How can I turn down an answer from Jeff?

Comment: It is probably my fault for being unclear and using loaded phrases like "I forgot". I wanted a means to flag my own questions as something I should go back and redo in some way - a bit like a star mark as Paulo notes, but that can easily be shown to me in the toolbar. I dont want a secretary, and really I had not forgotten I had asked it, I just remembered I wanted to do some work on your site and wanted your site to remind me next time I came.